# Hibernate One to One Mapping how to get status of current candidate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having two tables candidate and status table.  In candidate table  candId as a primary key and which is foreign key in status table.

Just an example I need to get status of a particular candidate in jsp. 
How to get status of current candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your candidate and status classes as following:
`Candidate.class`:

```
@Entity
public class Candidate{

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    @OneToOne
    private Status status;
}
```

`Status.class`:

```
@Entity
public class Status{

    private int id;

    private String value;
}
```

If you need more information about `OneToOne` mapping in Hibernate please visit this [link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html).

Comment: if i need to change the satus of particular candidate is it possible in spring

Comment: ya thanks for your fast reply is there any suggetion link for my refferencf

Comment: Please check following: https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example

Comment: I had  a doubt can we have status id as a  Auto increment